# Parse Installation Class has blank device token?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

When a user signs up and the device token is left blank in the installation class - does this mean the user just "declined" our prompt to allow push notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already got same issue, but automatic filled after few hour I save object to Parse Installation. Still  don't know what happen.